# Change md-input-container input type depending on var value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I want the input type of a `md-input-container` to be either text, a number or a date depending on the value of something I have defined in the scope.

To do that I created 3 different containers that have the same values everywhere but on the type property and use`ng-show` to changes the one visible depending on which one I need.

That part works just fine but when I write something on this field it runs the validations for the 3 data types and this shows many errors on the console:

```
"Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ngModel/datefmt?p0=1
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Array. (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:156:270)
    at Object. (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:228:41)
    at n.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:123:221)
    at b.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:293)
    at eg.$$debounceViewValueCommit (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:227:364)
    at eg.$setViewValue (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:227:92)
    at HTMLInputElement.l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:153:466)
    at HTMLInputElement.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:32:389)"
"Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ngModel/datefmt?p0=10
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Array. (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:156:270)
    at Object. (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:228:41)
    at n.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:123:221)
    at b.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:126:293)
    at eg.$$debounceViewValueCommit (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:227:364)
    at eg.$setViewValue (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:227:92)
    at HTMLInputElement.l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:153:466)
    at HTMLInputElement.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:32:389)"
```

I think this happens because they all have the same model, but since I will use the value in the same place I want this to be like that.

[Here is a codepen showing the problem.](http://codepen.io/lsarni/pen/mOPzNB?editors=1111)

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `ng-show` you can use `ng-if`.

ng-show creates an element in the dom, because the date input cannot parse the number to a  date it will throw an error.

Hope this helps!